# get max _id in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, max

I have this collection in mongodb with nodejs:

```
_id:
name:
email:
date:
```

I want to work with the max _id, i want the integer value.
I try this code but i dont know how to use after its found the max.

```
db.collection.find().sort({_id:-1}).limit(1)
```

i try alot codes with find and findone but i cant get the max int in _id.
i dont use the hex ids..
I need this to create new account with id that not used and the last account is the max _id.
some one have idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code prints the document with max `_id` value (tried in *mongo shell*):

```
var myCursor = db.test.find().sort( { _id: -1 } ).limit(1);

if (myCursor.hasNext()) {
    let doc = myCursor.next();
    printjson(doc);
}
```

The [db.collection.find()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/index.html) method returns a *cursor*. The *cursor* has a number of methods which you can apply on it and do various functions:[Cursor Methods](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/js-cursor/index.html).

---

*Code for NodeJS:*

```
db.test.find()
       .sort( [[ '_id', -1 ]] )
           .limit(1)
              .toArray( (err, docs) => {
                   if (docs.length > 0) { 
                       let maxId = docs[0]._id;
                       console.log(maxId);
                   }
                   else { 
                       console.log('Nothing found!');
                   } );
```

Comment: First of all thanks for the help, but when i write this in my code, it says printjson undefind

Comment: `printjson` is a _mongo shell_ command. What is it you are coding in?

Comment: I write in node js with modules of express and mongo db

Comment: Then, _printjson_ will not work there. In NodeJS code (that is JS) what do you want to do with the _max_ `_id` value? The field `doc._id` will have the value - you can `console.log` it and see.

Comment: With ._id i cant get the _id of the object, when i use findone i can do this but findone dont return the max value.

Comment: With `findOne` you will not get a cursor, but a document. You cannot find a max  value with one document. With `find` you get a cursor (with all the documents in the collection from them you can determine the max value.

Comment: See [findOne()](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.0/reference/method/db.collection.findOne/index.html) returns a document (not a cursor).

Comment: Okay, I added code that runs with the MongoDB NodeJS driver.

Comment: First of all the code working excellent and I understood everything you told me.
Second thing thank you for your help, I really appreciate your hard work.